# I try to show my users, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don´t know why my users are undefined in my console.log I can see them in my State but I can´t list them on the page ..
It showed up before where I have not yet used Redux .. after using Redux it no longer works that the users are displayed.

I'll show you a piece of the code where it should be displayed and how
My UserManagement.js:

```
function UserManagement({ history }) {
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.userList);
  const { loading  } = userLogin;
  const { users} = userList;

 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUsers());
  },[dispatch, history]);

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure? you want to delete")) {
      dispatch(deleteUserAction(id));
    }
  };

  
  console.log(userList);
  console.log(users);
  return (
    <MainScreen title={`List of Users`}>
       <Link to="/createUser" id="OpenCreateUserDialogButton">
        <Button style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 6 }} size="lg">
          Create new User
        </Button>
      </Link>
      
      {loading && <Loading />}
     
      {users &&
        users?.map((users) => (
         
          <Accordion>
            <Card style={{ margin: 10 }} key={users._id}>
              <Card.Header style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <span
                  // onClick={() => ModelShow(note)}
                  style={{
                    color: "black",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    flex: 1,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    fontSize: 18,
                  }}
                >
                      
                      {users.userID}               
                </span>
                <div>
                  <Link to="/profileedit">
                    <Button
                    id="EditButton"
                    >Edit</Button>
                    </Link>
                    <Button
                      id="DeleteButton"
                      variant="danger"
                      className="mx-2"
                      onClick={() => deleteHandler(users.id)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </div>
              </Card.Header>
```

I will show my Reducer function:

```
export const userListReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case USER_LIST_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
      case USER_LIST_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: true, userList: action.payload, success: true };
      case USER_LIST_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload, success: false };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

And this is my userAction:

```
  export const getUsers = (user) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: USER_LIST_REQUEST });
  
      const {
         userLogin: { userInfo },
        } = getState();
      
      const config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token.token}`,
        },
      };
      const url = "http://localhost:8080/user/"
      const { data } = await axios.get(url, config);
  
      dispatch({ type: USER_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  
    
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LIST_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_

Comment: You have a line where you map your users, but it currently says ` users?.map` do you need that question mark? Pretty sure that isn't Javascript syntax. You just want it to be Array.map() or in your case users.map()

Comment: try to put a console.log inside your useEffect, I suspect it's never called

Comment: @Shaded it doesn´t change anything .. but why is my console.log(users)  undefined. ..

Comment: @NickGr I got this .. useEffect(create, deps) { var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();.... and so on .. 

You meant this right console.log(useEffect);

Comment: No, inside your useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUsers());
   console.log("hello")
  },[dispatch, history]);
like this

Comment: @NickGr I got Hello on console .. I tried it now

Comment: You need to place the `console.log(userList)` in a `useEffect(() => {}, [userList])` to debug properly. You only get the value of `userList` when the reducer updates it, not when you render your component.

Comment: @PierreJanineh it´s undefined ..

Comment: The variable `users` is always `undefined`. Because you never assign it a value. You assigned it to the `userList` variable when it's still undefined (before the API request has finished).

Comment: So what should I do next that they will be displayed .. ? @PierreJanineh

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment on your question.

This is how you should be using a state variable.

```js
function UserManagement({ history }) {
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.userList);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUsers());
  },[dispatch, history]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userList);
  },[userList]);

  ...
}
```

If you still need to create another variable, you need to assign it a value every time `userList` changes - by adding this line to the `useEffect` method just like this.

```js
function UserManagement({ history }) {
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.userList);
  let users = userList;
 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUsers());
  },[dispatch, history]);

  useEffect(() => {
    users = userList;
  },[userList]);

  ...
}
```

**Notice** that when you assign a value to a variable like this:

The value assigned to that variable is the initial value of the assigned variable (undefined) because the reducer has not yet updated the state value. And when it actually updates it, nothing updates the second variable you created "`users`"

```js
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.userList);
  const users = userList;
```

And you can use it to manipulate your UI by:

```js
{userList &&
    userList.map((users) => (
        <MyComponent/>
    )
}
```

Comment: Ok it´s now not undefined anymore.. but how can I displayed them on the website ... it´s so annoying

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to always use `userList`.

Comment: Yeah :) thanks it works .. should I create a new Question or can I ask here why my deleteHandler deletes always the first user in the List and not the one which I select ?

Comment: Please open a separate question to make it clearer for other users.

Comment: Okey I will do now

Comment: Please mark my question as the correct answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment to this question,so check that too.

However I just noticed something else that should help you.

Due the the way state works your users are probably returning as `undefined`

You have two choices here.

1. Change your `users.map()` to `userList.users.map()` as userList.
2. If you really want it to just be `users.map()` then you might have to use some react state. For example

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; 
import { MyUserComponent } from 'some_file';

const YourComponent = () => {
  // grab your userList from redux
  const userList = useSelector(state => state.userList);
  
  // create some state for use the users
  // an empty array to start
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  
  // watch the userList for changes
  useEffect(() => {
    // update the users state whenever 
    // there is a change to useList
    setUsers(userlist.users)
    
  }, [userList])
  
  
  // do whatever you want in your return
  return (
    <div>
      { 
        users.map(user => <MyUserComponent {...user} key={`user-${index}`}) />
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Honestly I'd just do option 1

Comment: I did this {users &&
        userList.users.map((users) => ( but it doesn´t work @Shaded

Comment: Do your users show up in your [redux dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes under userList -> userList -> and there is a array full of users pin 0 -> ++

Comment: And you've got a `Provider` from `react-redux` set up? Also your state is `userList.userList` ?

Comment: Do you mean in store.js ?

Comment: I tried afterwards userList.userList.users .. but it doesn´t work

Comment: can you [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) your state?

Comment: You should have a [Provider](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider) wrapping your application to user the `useSelector` hook

Comment: {
  userList: {
    loading: true,
    userList: [
      {
            some data
      },
],
    success: true
  },

Comment: But it works now with userList.userList && userList.userList.map((users.....

Comment: Ah so you didn't have a `.users` part of your state then?

Comment: Okey I have done it :)

Comment: So now it works with users && users.map ..

Comment: Can you maybe help me on this .. Why it´s always deleting the first of the List if I click someone else on the list ..

Comment: Id need to see your delete action